# How to add the JSON data to NSARRAY?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlrequest

```
[{"name":"Mocha","latitude":17.418694 , "longitude":78.445116},
 {"name":"Rock Castle","latitude":17.420865 , "longitude":78.442219},
{"name":"RnB Select","latitude":17.420639 , "longitude":78.443635}
]
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
   location=locations.lastObject;
    [[self latitudeValue] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",location.coordinate.latitude]];
    [[self longnitudeValue] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",location.coordinate.longitude]];
//    [[self altitudeValue] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f feet",location.altitude*METERS_FEET]];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 2*METERS_MILE, 2*METERS_MILE);
    [[self mapView] setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
     NSArray *arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myStoredObject"];
    NSDictionary *zeroth=arr[0];
    NSLog(@"oth position,,,,%@",zeroth);
    NSDictionary *firstPosition = arr[1];
    NSLog(@"first position is .....%@",firstPosition);
    NSDictionary *secondPosition = arr[2];
    NSLog(@"second position is .....%@",secondPosition);


    MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    point2.coordinate =CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[firstPosition valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[firstPosition valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
    point2.title =[firstPosition valueForKey:@"name"];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];
    MKPointAnnotation *point3 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[firstPosition valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[firstPosition valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
    point3.title =[firstPosition valueForKey:@"name"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point3];

    MKPointAnnotation *point4 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point4.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[secondPosition valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[secondPosition valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
    point4.title =[secondPosition valueForKey:@"name"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point4];

MKCircle *circleoverlay = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:_mapView.userLocation.coordinate radius:1000];
    [circleoverlay setTitle:@"Circle"];
    [_mapView addOverlay:circleoverlay];
    NSLog(@"circle is drawn");




}
```

Above code showing the Json data...
 This is my JSON data which Iget from  URL by writing the below code

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *tRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ctrlm.in/kvikdata/locations.json"]];
        NSLog(@"url is %@",tRequest);
        [tRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [tRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:tRequest
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error) {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 NSError *error;
                 id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                  error:&error];
                 NSLog(@"Successfully deserialized.2222222..%@",jsonObject);
```

NSArray *myArr = [jsonObject copy]; // here myArr = yourData from your response. i take it nil for demonstrate
             NSLog(@"my array is %@",myArr);

```
       NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

         [myDefaults setObject:myArr forKey:@"myStoredObject"]; // by this you can store object

                 if (jsonObject != nil && error == nil){   
                     NSLog(@"Successfully deserialized...%@",jsonObject);
                 }
             });
         }
     }];
```

by writing the NSUserDefaults first data is updated as per the json object.. again when I change the names of the locations from @"mocha" to @"test1" it is not updating...why?
Thank u

Comment: The json data you posted looks like an array.

Comment: Can you please properly indent and generally clean up your code? It's more or more unreadable. Also be consistent, where you put spaces and where not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that you are getting is already array. Just use `NSArray * jsonObject` instead of `id jsonObject`. [Click here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394) for tutorial of tutsplus. [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started) is also good option as mentioned in another answer.

You should use `AFNetworking` to call web service. [AFNetworking - Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Hope this will help you. :)

Update as per question in comment :

You should use local database to store your dictionary or array whatever you are getting from server. If there is too much data and complex relations between data then you can use `sqlite` or `core data`. If thee is simple data (as shown in your question) you can use `NSUserDefaults` like below exampe,

```
 NSArray *myArr = nil; // here myArr = yourData from your response. i take it nil for demonstrate

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[myDefaults setObject:myArr forKey:@"myStoredObject"]; // by this you can store object


NSArray *arr = [myDefaults objectForKey:@"myStoredObject"]; // like this you can retrivie object
```

Now you can use arr to show annotation on map. whenever you get response from server call `[myDefaults setObject:myArr forKey:@"myStoredObject"];` and myArr should be new response. so it will override your old data with new. Hope this will help. :)

Comment: I'm getting json data from the url by writing the above code...I write the code for above three address using MKPointAnnotation..like below

Comment: Yes, there is no need  but if someone is not much familiar with this concepts then `afnetworking` can make their task little bit easy. :)

Comment: @nandini, What you trying to say? not getting your comment exactly! kike below means where?

Comment: I'm getting json data from the url by writing the above code.I write the code for above three address using MKPointAnnotation..like belowMKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.418694, 78.445116);
    point2.title = @"Mocha";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2]; I write same as remaining two address also...it is static..my question is ,if they change values in jsondata it should change dynamically in my code..How should I write code ? shall I store the json data in dictionary? thank u

Comment: hey, @nandini i have updated my answer as per your question. check it out. :)

Comment: @Lion, it is very useful to me and values are changing dynamically.Thank U

Comment: If you think this is helpful then upvote it and accept answer so other people can use it who have same issue!!. And you're welcome btw. :)

Comment: @Lion, Today I run the code by changing the Json data.But this method is not updating the values .It showing the previous value only..same name, lat and long values. when I check the apple.doc they said that NSUserDefaults invoke only once...Is there any way to get the updated Json data?

Comment: store new data every time when you get from completion handler. and if you want to keep record of previous data also then make a mutablearray and add object evrerytime to this array and store this array to userdefaults and display object from array which you want. you can use sqlite or core data to manage complex database and relational kind of database

Comment: @ I edit my code , check it once ,where I need to store my new data?

Comment: what this  NSLog(@"my array is %@",myArr); statement prints after updating data ?

Comment: it's a json object Lion...... NSArray myArr = [jsonobject copy]; it is working fine when I run the code in iPhone but it is not updating automatically

Comment: What i am asking, have you check that in console? response comes from server is it updated?

Comment: it's a json object Lion...... NSArray myArr = [jsonobject copy]; it is working fine when I run the code in iPhone but it is not updating automatically.....every time I need to run the code in iPhone...Is there any delegate is there in mapkit to update for every fewminiutes?...and also I need put those three Annotations in array..how should I write the loop?,

Comment: you can call this method from your appdelegate class means when your app launch. there is no way to auto update like your application is in inactive state and data change from server and it is got autoupdated. you can retrieve data first (show activity indicator till data us not sync) and display it after completion.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting array, use `NSArray` insted of `id` then you will get the reponse in array

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:& error];
```

**Suggesion**

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated in ios 9 so use `NSURLSession`

this may help you

https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/
https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Saving it to a id variables though, instead of NSArray

Comment: @trojanfoe : yes she just need the response in an array :)

Comment: @Lion, it is very useful to me and values are changing dynamically.Thank U